# Remaped the Tab key to the CAPS LOCK key but CAPS LOCKS still turning on and off?

Tags: keyboard

I created a .Xmodmap file and added the following:

```
keycode  66 = Tab ISO_Left_Tab Tab ISO_Left_Tab
keycode  23 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
```

df
So now my Caps Lock key works as a Tab but the Caps Lock still turning on and off (the CAPS light also turns on and off).

How can do it so that the CAPS don't turn on and off each time I press the Caps Lock Key which now works as a Tab?

EDIT:

I realized that it is only the light that turns on and off. Anyway, how to disable it?

(If that's something impossible to accomplish I guess I'll just have to cover it with a sticker).

Comment: Unless someone else has a suggestion, cover with a sticker sounds good ;P

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Then I should change this question to: "Which ubuntu sticker do you recommend to cover the Caps Lock light?"

Comment: hahahaha !!! This one : http://i44.tinypic.com/e128pj.png

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Nice one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [keytouch](http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/) to remap the keyboard. Worked with my Logitech Access sound controls and Internet/mail access buttons.

[image]